# How can i apply a theme to all my forms in C#?

Tags: c#, forms, themes

I want to Apply a theme to all my forms in c#. how can i do it?

i have too many forms. and they should all have the same style( orange background and a logo on top right) It is very time consuming. I would do it only once and it apply to all my forms.

Comment: please provide some code to tell us what have you tried so far and having diifficult with

Comment: @DivyaMV here more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For ASP.NET WEBForms**

You can use `MasterPage` and than add `Content Pages` inside it.

Add a `Master Page` in your project do all the designing in this back color logo and menus. Than add `Content Pages` which will have this `MasterPage`. So all your forms will have the same theme.

- Right Click on your website from `Solution Explorer`.
- Click `Add New Item`.
- Select `Master Page` from the popup which appears.

For details see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh(v=vs.140).aspx

**For Windows Forms**

You can use `MDI Parent`.

See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdiparent(v=vs.110).aspx) on how to use `MDI Parent`.

Comment: how can i use masterPage?

Comment: @Mahsa [Read here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deveshomar/master-page-in-C-Sharp-window-forms/)